# UICollectionView Layout

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView. How can I move the first cell of `UICollectionView`? I need to get a result like on the image. Shift is different for each section.

[image]

Comment: will be always three spaces?

Comment: No it is a dynamic value.

Comment: create two types of cells (first - green, second - clear) with different identifiers. Then, just return for first n indexPath.row  second type of cell in your cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method.

Comment: And so I did. Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: The other way is subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout and override layoutAttributesForElementsInRect method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a dummy cell that you use for the first 3 cells of your collectionView. I went ahead and tested it out and it worked correctly. It's not completely desirable because you can't reference index 0 as being the visually apparent cell 0.

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell;

if (indexPath.row < self.dynamicNumberValue) {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifierDummy";
    cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
} else {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";
    cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    collectionViewCell *collectionCell = (collectionViewCell *)cell;
    [collectionCell.cellLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.cellNumber]];
    self.cellNumber++;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I need to move only the first line.